# How to install features in wso2 using OSGI Console

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I am new to wso2.. I have searched through articles and found that ,we can install features into carbon using OSGI Console... For eg,I want to install student management feature (Sample) in wso2 carbon,without using feature management(**without UI**) .

How to do this... I have the REPO in my local (Say D://p2-repo) I want to install these features in carbon using OSGI console

Steps Tried

1) Started wso2 in OSGI console (`bin\wso2server.bat -DosgiConsol`)
2) Then i need to add the Repo right? 
3) i tried `provaddrepo` command

Say **provaddrepo file://D:/p2-repo**

My p2-repo structure is 
**features folder,plugins folder,content.jar,artifact.jar**

But while doing this, i am getting the error like below

```
`osgi> provaddrepo file://C:/Users/473294nneh/Desktop/p2-repo
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: \\C\Users\473294nneh\Desktop\p2-repo\artifacts.xml (The network path was not found)
            at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
            at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:212)
            at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:165)
            at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.simple.SimpleArtifactRepository.save(SimpleArtifactRepository.java:1187)
            at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.simple.SimpleArtifactRepository.save(SimpleArtifactRepository.java:1168)
            at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.simple.SimpleArtifactRepository.<init>(SimpleArtifactRepository.java:348)
            at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.simple.SimpleArtifactRepositoryFactory.create(SimpleArtifactRepositoryFactory.java:134)
            at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.ArtifactRepositoryManager.factoryCreate(ArtifactRepositoryManager.java:61)
            at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.helpers.AbstractRepositoryManager.doCreateRepository(AbstractRepositoryManager.java:286)
            at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.ArtifactRepositoryManager.createRepository(ArtifactRepositoryManager.java:49)
            at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.console.ProvisioningHelper.addArtifactRepository(ProvisioningHelper.java:87)
            at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.console.ProvCommandProvider._provaddrepo(ProvCommandProvider.java:83)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
            at org.eclipse.equinox.console.command.adapter.CommandProviderAdapter.main(CommandProviderAdapter.java:46)
            at org.eclipse.equinox.console.command.adapter.CommandProviderAdapter._main(CommandProviderAdapter.java:64)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
            at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Reflective.method(Reflective.java:136)
            at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.CommandProxy.execute(CommandProxy.java:82)
            at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.executeCmd(Closure.java:469)
            at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.executeStatement(Closure.java:395)
            at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Pipe.run(Pipe.java:108)
            at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.execute(Closure.java:183)
            at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.execute(Closure.java:120)
            at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.CommandSessionImpl.execute(CommandSessionImpl.java:89)
            at org.apache.felix.gogo.shell.Console.run(Console.java:62)
            at org.apache.felix.gogo.shell.Shell.console(Shell.java:203)
            at org.apache.felix.gogo.shell.Shell.gosh(Shell.java:128)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
            at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Reflective.method(Reflective.java:136)
            at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.CommandProxy.execute(CommandProxy.java:82)
            at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.executeCmd(Closure.java:469)
            at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.executeStatement(Closure.java:395)
            at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Pipe.run(Pipe.java:108)
            at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.execute(Closure.java:183)
            at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.execute(Closure.java:120)
            at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.CommandSessionImpl.execute(CommandSessionImpl.java:89)
            at org.apache.felix.gogo.shell.Activator.run(Activator.java:75)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)`
```

As i told,i am new to wso2..>CAN anyone please help me to resolve this issue...

I have used this article (http://wiki.eclipse.org/Equinox_p2_Console_Users_Guide)

CAN anyone please help me to resolve this issue...Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

I believe that it may simply be an extra forward slash in your URI after "file:".

Try this:

```
osgi> provaddrepo file:/C:/Users/473294nneh/Desktop/p2-repo
```