# How to install features in WSO2 using a shell script

Tags: installation, automation, docker, wso2

I'm building customised Docker images based on basic WSO2 products images.

I'd like to automate the installation of WSO2 features. There are two [documented methods](https://docs.wso2.com/display/Carbon420/Installing+Features) to do this: using the UI and using a pom file (which I tried without success). There is also a command-line approach using an [OSGI console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22753837/how-to-install-features-in-wso2-using-osgi-console), but it is not scriptable.

What do you suggest?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should look at the 87 images about WSO2 in the Docker Hub

https://registry.hub.docker.com/search?q=wso2&searchfield=

More generally, you can always do something like

`docker run -it image_name while true; do echo hi ; sleep 100; done`

then enter this container with

`docker exec -it container_id bash`

then install your software, then

`docker commit -t maysoft`

Sometimes it is not possible to automate everything